# Set Keywords in two specific colors inside of a codeblock

Tags: color, code, keywords

Is it possible to set two Colors to Keywords inside of a Codeblock?

I have the current settings for my Codeblock

```
\lstset{language=[Sharp]C,
captionpos=b,
%numbers=left, %Nummerierung
%numberstyle=\tiny, % kleine Zeilennummern
frame=lines, % Oberhalb und unterhalb des Listings ist eine Linie
showspaces=false,
showtabs=false,
numbers=left,
basicstyle = small,
breaklines=true,
showstringspaces=false,
breakatwhitespace=true,
escapeinside={(*@}{@*)},
commentstyle=\color{greencomments},
morekeywords={HaarCascade, Image, partial, var, value, get, set},
keywordstyle=\color{bluekeywords},
stringstyle=\color{redstrings},
basicstyle=\ttfamily\small,
}
```

I can defince such keywords as `HaarCascade` or `Image`, and they would appear in my code as blue. But what can I to set those two specific keywords in another color, lets say turquoise?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!! It is better to post a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) that starts with a `\documentclass` command, has a minimal preamble and then `\begin{document}...\end{document}`. Unless the problem is a compilation error, the code should compile and be as small as possible to demonstrate your problem. This makes it much easier for people to help you --- and much ore likely that they will!

Comment: Fir your question, see page 31 of the [listings](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/listings) manual. In particular, the use of `classoffset`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use any number of different keyword classes with the syntax `keyword=[class]...` and `keywordstyle=[class]...`. `class` is just a natural number used as id for the class.

In your case:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[usenames]{xcolor}

\definecolor{turquoise}{RGB}{64, 224, 208}
\colorlet{greencomments}{green!50!black}
\colorlet{bluekeywords}{blue}
\colorlet{redstrings}{red}

\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{language=[Sharp]C,
captionpos=b,
%numbers=left, %Nummerierung
%numberstyle=\tiny, % kleine Zeilennummern
frame=lines, % Oberhalb und unterhalb des Listings ist eine Linie
showspaces=false,
showtabs=false,
numbers=left,
basicstyle = small,
breaklines=true,
showstringspaces=false,
breakatwhitespace=true,
escapeinside={(*@}{@*)},
commentstyle=\color{greencomments},
morekeywords=[1]{partial, var, value, get, set},
morekeywords=[2]{HaarCascade, Image},
keywordstyle=\color{bluekeywords},
keywordstyle=[2]\color{turquoise},
stringstyle=\color{redstrings},
basicstyle=\ttfamily\small,
}
\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
using System;
// From wikipedia
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello, world!");
        Image img;
    }
}
HaarCascade, Image, partial, var, value, get, set
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image: preview]